# Bilingual website usability

Tags: website-design

Can anyone provide me with links to research material stating best usability practice is *not* to develop websites with content written in two languages, but rather seperating content into two independent sites.

Comment: Id actually be interested in any research that says best practice *is* to develop multi lingual sites as a single site. Going through this very process now, and looking for ideas on how best to do it.

Comment: From experience of facilitating user testing sessions, I have seen people become frustrated quite easily because they fail to understand half the website content and struggle to use a duplicated primary navigation.  So I am pretty certain that the best way to deal with this issue is to develop independent websites connected together via the top website banner.

Comment: Gavin makes a true statement, but usually when we do multilingual it's not 2 languages, but several with ability to add others (using tagged content). I don't think developing lots of sites and adding when you need new language is the answer. Sorry.

Comment: No specific research, but to add to the conversation, different languages often involve different cultures, which ultimately can mean very different demographics/personas to be targetting.

Comment: One for Nathan above

The German Railways site just about pulls off the complications of dealing with European languages and culture...

http://www.bahn.de

Comment: what is meant by seperate sites here? I think there are two things this could mean- a good one, in that abc.fr and abc.de will be broadly the same but in different languages, and a bad one- in that abc.fr will be a lovely fully featured site...but will have a page or two in German with minimal info.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit 8 November 2010**

I found one more good link today

8 Tips For Designing Better Global Websites

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/8-tips-for-designing-better-global-websites/

---

> - Have country specific domains - it's better for search engines and better
>     for users to find you - in other words
>     .ie .fr .nl .jp etc. If you can't get
>     country specific use sub-domains -
>     fr.yourdomain.com. An example of this
>     is Yahoo!
> - Don't mix the languages on the same part of your site ie have two or three
>     languages on the same page.
> - Make sure the page defines what the language is in the code - this helps
>     with the browsers but also search
>     engines.
> - If you want to create a language 'chooser' - the ideal way is to have a
>     portal where you make the selection -
>     maybe a .com or .org portal.
> - Translate and optimise before you launch your site. (Have the
>     tranlations checked too!)
> - Choose the languages you target based on real need - not on ease of
>     translation (you may not be doing this
> - but some Web Certain research to be published soon suggests languages are
>     often added because they were
>     relatively 'easy' rather than
>     important target languages - and if
>     the alphabet is not roman - it's less
>     likely to be used.)
> - Make sure you can back up the language with the service - in other
>     words have a speaker of the language -
>     or at least explain that the user will
>     need to read English or another
>     language - to view or use the site.
> - Don't 'force' language based on country - urdu speakers may well be
>     British based in the UK. Nacho's given
>     you two very good examples to consider
>     in Epson and Greenpeace - but my
>     advice would be to allow the user to
>     choose the language AND location if
>     both are appropriate. Take Belgium on
>     the Epson example - that asks you to
>     choose Belgium - then to choose
>     between French and Flemish with French
>     at the top of the screen. There are
>     twice as many Flemish-speakers as
>     French in Belgium and they might have
>     expected top-billing. Equally, German
>     is also an official language of
>     Belgium (67,000 speakers) and is not
>     represented, English is used by many
>     of the institutions in Brussels. It's
>     complicated - allowing a choice of
>     language would be best.
> - Check your links, navigation and error messages are in the target
>     language too - it's a common mistake
>     for error pages to show up in the
>     wrong language. (A site I looked at
>     the other day gave an error message in
>     German, had a French title and content
>     in English....)
> - Test before you invest (phrase stolen from San Jose conference but
>     can't remember who used it?) Look at
>     using pay per clicks to trial your
>     approach before you roll it out across
>     all languages.
>
> Good luck!
>   refrence - http://forums.searchenginewatch.com/archive/index.php/t-1156.html

and

> If you can afford it, it’s best to
>   have a dedicated Top Level Domain for
>   each of your target countries (for
>   instance, www.wesellstuff.co.uk for
>   the UK and www.wesellstuff.cn for
>   China) as this will help to improve
>   your ranking with country-specific
>   search engines.
>
> Best to avoid going for separate
>   sub-domains (for example,
>   http://cn.wesellstuff.com) as search
>   engines will view sub-domains more or
>   less as the same site as the TLD and
>   you will lose any of the relevancy
>   generated by your carefully
>   constructed in-country SEO techniques.
>
> With this in mind, you’re also best
>   ensuring that your webhost for each of
>   your in-country websites has its
>   server based ‘in-country’. Some
>   webhosts use servers based in another
>   country and given that Google uses
>   this data in its search algorithm,
>   it’s of real benefit to each of your
>   websites to have everything as
>   localised as possible.

reference - http://www.thewebsqueeze.com/web-design-articles/how-to-make-your-website-multilingual.html

I found these articles are worth to read

Multi-Language Web Development
http://www.stylusinc.com/website/multilanguage_support.htm

Tips for planning multi-language websites
http://econsultancy.com/blog/5763-tips-for-planning-multi-language-websites

Comment: the forcing language to match country thing is one of my biggest hates as an English speaker in French speaking Switzerland who always has to wrestle with German language sites (*angry glare at paypal*)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

[How Should Language Selection be Displayed on the Web?](https://web.archive.org/web/20110816010304/http://imagexmedia.com/support/faqs/general-questions/how-should-language-selection-be-displayed-web)